# How to programatically issue a certificate from a self signed certificate with openssl?

Tags: c, openssl, certificate, x509

I manage to create a self signed certificate, but now I would like to be able to issue other certificates with this self signed certificate. How can this be done in C using openssl library?

Comment: Not sure how to do this in pure C, but can't you just call the `openssl` command?

Comment: no because I was trying to do a full programatically implementation. So I needed this to work like this.

Comment: I managed to find this, and work with the command line. this is not perfect but might solve me some problems by the time: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/be-your-own-ca/#comment-19436 . This is using RSA, but I would like to do the same with ECDSA does anyone know what do I need to change? Thanks Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

first create a certificate request and a private key:

```
X509_REQ *req;
EVP_PKEY *pk;
RSA *rsa;
X509_NAME *name=NULL;

if ((pk=EVP_PKEY_new()) == NULL)
  return false;

if ((req=X509_REQ_new()) == NULL)
  return false;

rsa=RSA_generate_key(SSL_KEY_BITS,RSA_F4,NULL,NULL);
if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pk,rsa))
  return false;
rsa=NULL;

X509_REQ_set_pubkey(req,pk);
name=X509_REQ_get_subject_name(req);

X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name,"C",MBSTRING_ASC, "AT", -1, -1, 0);
X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name,"CN", MBSTRING_ASC, "CommonName", -1, -1, 0);

if (!X509_REQ_sign(req,pk,EVP_sha1()))
  return false;
return true;
```

sign the request with the ca private key, paramter: X509* cacert, EVP_PKEY* ca_key

```
#define SSL_KEY_DAYS 366*20
EVP_PKEY *pkey;
x509 *x=NULL; // temporary certificate
X509* ssl_cert=NULL;
X509_CINF *ci;
X509_STORE *ctx;

// Public Key Check
pkey=X509_REQ_get_pubkey(req);
if(pkey == NULL)
  return false;
if (X509_REQ_verify(req,pkey) < 0)
  return false;
EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

ctx = X509_STORE_new();
X509_STORE_set_default_paths(ctx);
X509_set_version(x,2);

x=X509_new();
if (x == NULL)
  return false;
ci=x->cert_info;

ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(x),SSL_SERIAL);

if (!X509_set_issuer_name(x,req->req_info->subject))
  return false;
if (!X509_set_subject_name(x,req->req_info->subject))
  return false;

X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x),0);
X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x),(long)60*60*24*SSL_KEY_DAYS);

pkey = X509_REQ_get_pubkey(req);
X509_set_pubkey(x,pkey);

EVP_PKEY *upkey;
X509_STORE_CTX xsc;
upkey = X509_get_pubkey(cacert);
EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters(upkey,pkey);
EVP_PKEY_free(upkey);

if(!X509_STORE_CTX_init(&xsc,ctx,x,NULL))
  return false;

if (!X509_set_issuer_name(x,X509_get_subject_name(cacert)))
  return false;

if(!X509_sign(x,ca_key,EVP_sha1()))
  return false;

ssl_cert = X509_dup(x);

EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
X509_STORE_CTX_cleanup(&xsc);
X509_STORE_free(ctx);
X509_free(x);
return true;
```